# How to use Emacs to open an eshell from Terminal at a specific path

Tags: eshell, term, shell-command

By default, if I invoke emacs from terminal by typing `$ emacs C:\users` a directory-like environment opens. Then if I do `M-x eshell`, an eshell environment opens at this path.

My question is how to directly go to this eshell from the initial terminal. I tried `$ emacs C:\users eshell` and `$ emacs C:\users M-x eshell` but they don't work.

Added: As an application of the below solution of abo-abo, on Microsoft OS, if at the path bar of your window directory, you type `emacs -f eshell`, an `eshell` will be opened at that directory:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like this:

```
emacs C:\users -f eshell
```

Comment: Perfect thank you. Just by curiosity what is `-f`? Abbreviated of what?

Comment: Call function, probably. It should be in `emacs --help`.